# Huge difference between "cycle" and "eevee"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, z-fighting

I rendered some of the objects in "eevee" mode and "cycle" mode, and find that there is a huge difference between them. When in "cycle" mode, there seem to be "z-fighting". I wonder how can I eliminate the "z-fighting" when rendering in "cycle" mode as it is in "eevee" mode.

[image: eevee mode]

[image: cycle mode]

[image]

Comment: so why don't you simply clean up your mesh so that you don't have Z fighting (overlapping faces)?

Comment: maybe also watch some tutorials about "clean topology" because your mesh has a chaotic topology....

Comment: @moonboots ShapeNetCore is huge, if I clean up them manually, it will take a lot of time. If there is a way to clean up them automatically in python?

Comment: @Chris I will have a look at it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z fight is present when there isn't enough distance between two coplanar faces in the direction of camera.

As Eevee is something like a rasterizer it has an internal (tweakable) resolution, which can differ from how Cycles reads the scene in its Raytracer way.

How much is this "enough"? It depends by your Clip Start and End values of the camera, as the internal resolution is distribuited into thoose values: so it's a good habit to set thoose values as close to the actual needs as possible.

Also modeling without coplanar faces is a good habit, of course.

[image]

Comment: I modified the camera's "clip" property, however, the problem still exist. Could you please download the .blend file I have uploaded and do some examination? I am really a newbie of blender

Comment: There are many issues in your file, I think you should search some tutorials about basics of 3D modeling and topology  good practices. Anyway It's an error to leave two identical meshes one on top of the other (and there's no need, nor advantages on such practices).